# JSON ordering and logging response/request body in envoy

Tags: proxy, envoyproxy

I am using envoy proxy in my application and I am trying to print logs in these three ways:

1. In fixed ORDERING JSON format
2. Need to add request and response body of the request to log
3. Can we add a route level logging (enable/disabling), not with Lua?

All below scenarios log level is added in listener filter in my application.

**#1:**
I am able to add `stdout` access logging and able to print logs in JSON format but not able to **order them** in a fixed format like first key should be response code and so on. Each time JSON log prints order of keys changes.

**#2:** In my logs how can I add my request and response body? I tried to find formats supported by the envoy but had no luck.

What extra parameters do I need to in `json_format` to get the body?

```
 json_format": {"protocol": "%PROTOCOL%","duration": "%DURATION%","my_custom_header": "%REQ(MY_CUSTOM_HEADER)%"}
```

**#3:** Can we add **route level logging** in envoy and also enable/disable on route level? I read the documentation but was not able to find anything.

In Lua we can add like below on route level can we do without Lua/another plugin?

```
envoy.filters.http.lua:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.LuaPerRoute
   # name: bye.lua
   disabled : true
```

Comment: Which istio version did you use? Please also edit your question and paste your code as text. Don't use images.

Comment: I am using envoy not istio.

Comment: You have used the istio tag, hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, I have same question with you on #1. It's terrible that we can't control JSON order for the access log.

For #2, I don't think print request body is a good idea. You can try to log request body in your application and track envoy log and your application log with the same `x-request-id`.

For #3, I don't have further knowledge for lua filter. But enovy access log itself has many fields for UPSTEAM and DOWNSTREAM.

Hope you have already resolved the issue and share back : )

Comment: for #1 I didn't find any order but for Prometheus, in my case, just JSON is needed not required ordering for now. #2 correct it's not good to print in logs but for debugging i need it but am not able to find anything #3. without Lua we cant log on route level or enable and disbale them